# How do I read through a CSV file twice and print certain rows based on arguments passed through the function?

Tags: python, csv

I am having trouble with reading through a CSV file and printing out a row based on whether or not a string value exists in that row. Here is my current code:

```
main("Fuel")
main("Temp")
```

^This is the main function that will take a string as an argument and pass it through another function.

```
def main(String):
with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for field in row:
            if field == String: 
                print(row)
```

^This is the function that will take the argument from above "Fuel" and "Temp" and look for it in a CSV file. If it finds it, it will print the row out.

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| Fuel | X116.75 Y151 Z175 |
| Fuel | X138.50 Y151 Z175 |
| Fuel | X160.25 Y151 Z175 |
|  |  |
| Temp | X138.50 Y93 Z225 |
| Temp | X160.25 Y122 Z225 |
| Temp | X116.75 Y93 Z225 |

^ This is CSV file that I am reading from

When I execute my code I am able to print out all of the "Fuel" rows, but all of the "Temp" rows do not get printed. Here is my output:

```
['Fuel', 'X116.75', 'Y151', 'Z175']
['Fuel', 'X138.5', 'Y151', 'Z175']
['Fuel', 'X160.25', 'Y151', 'Z175']
```

Even if I have `main("Temp")` in front of `main("Fuel")`, nothing gets printed as well. It seems like the program will only iterate through the first row. How do I change my program so that it can read through the whole file each time and print all the rows that have the string value in it?

Comment: Your code is not inside your function. Indent it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean can you elaborate? My main function takes the string and looks for the string in my csv file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main function should iterate over `reader` instead of `data`.

```
def main(s):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                if field == s:
                    print(row)
```

Comment: Hi Dan, Thank you for your reply. That was my mistake, I should have had "reader" there instead of data". Even after I changed it, "Temp" would not be printed. I changed the word "Temp" to some other name and it worked! I think the word "Temp" is a special case in excel.

Comment: You can accept the answer by toggling the greyed out check mark beside it. Welcome to Stackoverflow! More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers